# Referencing class for function when function is called from html element

Tags: javascript

I've got a class that assigns an eventListener to an html element when its loaded. When that html element is clicked, it invokes a function from that same class like so:

```
class LiveViewController extends ViewController{

viewLoads(){
    $("#mydiv")[0].addEventListener("click",this.someFunction);
}

someFunction(){
    console.log(this);
}

}
```

The issue is that i would like to somehow have a reference of the instance of the class in `someFunction` but "this" refers to the element itself. What would be your suggested way of doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify a function to be used as an event handler in jQuery, that function gets access to the raw DOM element that initiated the event as `this`. So the classical solution would be to closure the class context inside the handler as `self`:

```
class LiveViewController extends ViewController{

  viewLoads(){
    var self = this;
    $("#mydiv")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
      self.someFunction(self);
    });
  }
  someFunction(context){
    console.log(context);
  }
}
```

You even don't need to pass the context at all:

```
class LiveViewController extends ViewController{

  viewLoads(){
    var self = this;
    $("#mydiv")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
      self.someFunction();
    });
  }
  someFunction(){
    console.log(this);
  }
}
```

At last you may use `.bind` to bind appropriate context:

```
class LiveViewController{
  viewLoads(){
    $("#mydiv")[0].addEventListener("click", this.someFunction.bind(this));
  }
  someFunction(){
    console.log(this);
  }
}
```

To get an access to both of instantiated object and dom element you may use

```
class LiveViewController extends ViewController{

  viewLoads(){
    var self = this;
    $("#mydiv")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
      self.someFunction(this);
    });
  }
  someFunction(element){
    console.log(this);
    console.log(element);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why cant i +5 this?

Comment: @GeorgeAvgoustis You also may "accept" this answer.

Comment: I will, just waiting for the time limit. Not to stretch it but.. how would i go about if i wanted to have access BOTH to the class AND the element?

Comment: Ok thats a good way. Is it too stupid to do :         $("#rollDieDiv")[0].addEventListener("click",this.rollDiePressed.bind({"element":$("#rollDieDiv")[0],"classInstance":this})); ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 class LiveViewController extends ViewController {

     viewLoads(){
         // You can pass data to the callback directly as event.data in jQuery
         $("#mydiv").on('click', {self: this}, this.someFunction);  

         // or Another way would be to use bind
         // $("#mydiv").click(this.someFunction.bind($, this));
         // someFunction(self, event) - definition
     }

     someFunction(event){
        console.log(event.data.self);
     }
  }
```